# Why do I keep getting 405 error when submitting a form to mysql database

Tags: php, database, forms, web, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to submit a form into mysql database but every time I click submit on the webpage I'm getting the HHTP ERROR 405 Method not allowed. I've searched but I still haven't found a solution, can anyone help? Here is my code below.

Here is the requests.html page

```
form action="conn.php" method="POST">

                <label for="category" id="fname">What type of request are you making?</label>
                <select id="category" name="category" required>
                  <option value="software">Software Update</option>
                  <option value="hardware">Hardware </option>
                  <option value="application">Application</option>
                  <option value="security">Security</option>
                 
                </select>

              <label for="fname" id="fname" >Full Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Your name.." required>
          
              <label for="fname" id="fname">Summary</label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="summary" placeholder="Brief summary..." required>

              <label for="lname">Description</label>
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="description" placeholder="">

              <label for="fname" id="fname">Impact on server or application</label>
              <select id="category" name="server_category" required>
                <option value="sql">MySQL</option>
                <option value="web">EA Webserver </option>
                <option value="server">Oracle Server</option>
              </select>

              <label for="fname" id="fname">Impact on Department</label>
              <select id="category" name="department_category" required>
                <option value="assurance">ICT ASSURANCE SERVICE</option>
                <option value="support">ICT Support Service </option>
                <option value="network">ICT Network and infastructure</option>
              </select>

              <label for="fname">Risk</label>
              <select id="category" name="risk_category">
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="moderate">Moderate</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
              </select>

              <!--<label for="fname">Change Start date</label>
              <input type="date" id="date" name="start_date">
              
              <label for="fname">Change Completion date</label>
              <input type="date" id="date" name="end_date">
              -->
              
          
             
            
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

And here is the conn.php code

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$server = $_POST['server_category'];
$department = $_POST['department_category'];
$risk = $_POST['risk_category'];
$start = $_POST['start_date'];
$end = $_POST['end_date'];

if(!empty($name) || !empty($summary) || !empty($description) || !empty($server) || !empty($department) || !empty($risk)){


$passw = "dog1234";
   
$username = "root";

$db = "test";

$host = "localhost";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $passw, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die('Connection error ('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
} else{
    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO request_change (employee_name, summary, req_description, req_server, department, risk) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $summary, $description, $server, $department, $risk);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "new record inserted";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();


} else{
    echo "All fields are required";
    die();
}
?>
```

Please can anyone let me know if my code is wrong or if there is something I'm missing out on here.

Comment: `form action="...">` is missing an opening `<`, is that a typo?

Comment: Unrelated: you have multiple elements with the same `id="fname"` - which is invalid. `id`s need to be unique

Comment: We can't tell why your server is telling you that you can't make POST requests to that URL since you haven't told us anything about the server you are using. We don't know which server it is. We don't know how you have configured it.

Comment: @brombeer yeah that was just a typo when copying across my code but the opening   of the form is there. I'll also take on board your id info.

Comment: @Quentin its just my standard local host 127.0.0.1 I have running on so I haven't configured anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: @PhillipM1 — Having any kind of HTTP server at all on localhost is out of the ordinary so you must have configured *something*. Wild guess: You are using VS Code Live Server?

Comment: @Quentin Yeah thats what I'm using. Is that not appropriate? What do you recommend?

Comment: Since it doesn't support PHP (or any other kind of server side programming) it isn't appropriate for running PHP. I have no particular recommendations for PHP friendly HTTP servers (and even fewer when I don't know the target operating system).

Comment: @Quentin Ok thanks for clearing all of this up for me anyway, much appreciated.